# Find multiple results using different conditions MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So my problem is that I have a collection of articles. My goal is to get many different variations of arrays back from the collection. The only way I can think of right now is chaining. It does not seem the best option.

What I have right now.

```
const shownIDs = [];
const news = {};

Post.find({ _id: { $nin: shownIDs }, active: true, tags: { $in: ["garden"] } }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(6).exec().then(g => {

    const gardenNews = sortByLevel(g).slice(0, 3);
    gardenNews.forEach(h => { shownIDs.push(h._id) });
    news.garden = gardenNews;

    return news;
})
.then(e => {

    Post.find({ _id: { $nin: shownIDs }, active: true, tags: { $in: ["lifestyle"] } }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(6).exec().then(lifestyle => {

        const lifestyleNews = sortByLevel(lifestyle).slice(0, 3);
        lifestyleNews.forEach(h => { shownIDs.push(h._id) });
        news.lifestyle = lifestyleNews;

        return news;
    })
    .then(e => {

        Post.find({ _id: { $nin: shownIDs }, active: true }).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(25).exec().then(more => {

            news.more = more;

            return news;

        })
        .then(e => {
            res.status(200).json(e);
        })


    })


})
```

There are some sorting functions which in the perfect world would be replaced by the query conditions.

And now let's say I would have like 20 more topics, would it still be effective?

So my overall concern is that how to do it the right way? I am pretty sure that this is not the right way. There must be something more effective and clean.

Comment: show your datas.